# How do you queryOrderedByValue on a key that is auto-generated in Swift?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I need to `queryOrderedByValue()` on a node whose key is auto-generated. My database is structured as per pic below (/users-pings/$uid/$uid/"auto-id").

What changes can I make to my query below to achieve this?

```
REF_USERS_PINGS.child(currentUid).child(forId).queryOrderedByValue().queryEqual(toValue: "true").observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in


            if snapshot.exists(){

                handler(true)

            } else {

                handler(false)
            }
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firebase Database queries run on each child node under the location where you run them, so they autoskip the third level under `user-pings` in your case.

You just need to specify what property to order/filter on, which seems to be `active` here. So something like:

```
REF_USERS_PINGS.child(currentUid).child(forId).queryOrdered(byChild: "active").queryEqual(toValue: "true").observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
```

Comment: aha! this makes complete sense and it worked! - thanks so much for your help :)

Comment: a quick question: If i want to add an additional order/filter (eg; type), can I bind an additional  `queryOrdered(byChild: "type").queryEqual(toValue: "compliment")` to the query?

Comment: @Roggie No. Queries are for single children only. Uou cannot query where active = true *and* type = compliment. But you can store compound values and query on that. For example add another child node to your structure: type_active: "compliment_true". Note: potential issue in your structure; storing a bool value as a string "true" which is not equal to true so be careful if you query by that as if you are looking for a bool of true, you wont find it. Check out [compound value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45433558/how-to-apply-multiple-filter-in-firebase-query-in-swift/45469440#45469440)

Comment: As Jay said, Firebase Database queries can only order/filter on a single property. In many cases it is possible to combine the values you want to filter on into a single (synthetic) property. For an example of this and other approaches, see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26700924/query-based-on-multiple-where-clauses-in-firebase

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `queryOrderedByKey()` to return result related to that id only:

```
REF_USERS_PINGS.child(currentUid).child(forId).queryOrderedByKey().queryEqual(toValue: "-LH72MNIVX8o4KI3V9nL").observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
```

more info here:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/lists-of-data#data_order

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, but this does not solve the problem, `LH72MNIVX8o4KI3V9nL` is auto-generated so this value will not be known in advance.